# SQL Occurence character Replace issue

Tags: sql, oracle, replace, regexp-replace

I'm working on Oracle's SQL and I would like to have the following results :

```
4,500,400,40 --> 4 500 400,40

5400200,00   --> 5 400 200,00

1200,988,00  --> 1 200 988,00
```

I tried to use `REGEXP_REPLACE` but with no result, so if someone could help me if would be wonderful.

Thanks.

Comment: are the values always having a comma in the 3rd position from the end? if they do - that this could be solved by simple replace and then formatting

Comment: Not really, in some cases the value is like : 60000.

Comment: If the value is **60000**, should it be displayed as **60 000** or **600,00**. Please see the answer @Littlefoot has placed

Comment: It should be displayed as 60 000,00. I tried @littlefoot's answer and it's working fine. But sitll, I'm having another problem :

40 500 600 --> 40 500 600,00
28 200 600,5 --> 40 500 600,50

How should I format this? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '4,500,400,40' from dual union all
  3     select '5400200,00'   from dual union all
  4     select '1200,988,00'  from dual union all
  5     select '28 200 600,5' from dual union all
  6     select '40 500 600'   from dual
  7    )
  8  select col,
  9  to_char(
 10    to_number(  replace(  replace(case when instr(col, ',') = 0 then col ||',00'
 11                                       else col
 12                                  end,
 13                                  ' ', ','
 14                                 ),
 15                          ',', ''
 16                        )
 17             ) / 100,
 18                 'fm999G999G999G990D00',
 19                 'nls_numeric_characters = '', '''
 20                ) result
 21  from test;

COL          RESULT
------------ -------------------
4,500,400,40 4 500 400,40
5400200,00   5 400 200,00
1200,988,00  1 200 988,00
28 200 600,5 2 820 060,05
40 500 600   40 500 600,00

SQL>
```

What does it do (now that it got more complicated)?

- nested `REPLACE`:

  - inner checks whether source string contains comma `,` character; if not, appends `,00` suffix (that's for values like `'40 500 600'`)
  - outer is as before - substitutes commas with an empty string
- `to_number` converts such a string into a number
- it is divided by `100`
- `to_char` formats it

Comment: Thank you very much, it works wonderfully: D. For cases without commas at the end, I simply added ', 00' and used your solution.

Comment: Can I ask you another question please.

I want to do the following format :

40 500 600 --> 40 500 600,00 

28 200 600,5 --> 40 500 600,50

Comment: I modified code I previously wrote; have a look, please.